# Can't sync all iBooks from mac to other devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, books

I have done everything possible, starting from reading this :
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202759

I have set the sync option on the mac , and also on the iPhone/iPad.

When I buy a book **outside** the *Apple store*, i put it on my mac, then I would like to be able to see it on iPhone/iPad iBooks , but I just don't see it.

It would be wonderful if I could start reading on the mac and move to the iPhone.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Wouldn't surprise me at all if that only applies to books from the iTunes Store.

Comment: The link? Yes it is, the question is how can one simply start reading on the iPad and continue on the iPhone. Such a simple thing to ask from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

> Yes, it's possible.
>
> The article you linked to applies only to books from iTunes Store. In
>   order to sync your books and PDFs outside of the iTunes Store you need
>   an iOS device running iOS 9.3 or later and/or a Mac running Mac OS X
>   10.11.4 (El Capitan) or later. You may update from App Store or iTunes.
>
> Also check:
>   iCloud Drive should be turned **ON** for all
>   devices 
>   Enable iBooks in iCloud Drive (Settings->iCloud->iCloud
>   Drive->iBooks for iOS and Systemsettings->iCloud->iBooks for Mac) 
>   Make sure that you have some free space for the books on iCloud Drive
>   
>   Make sure you are signed in with same Apple ID on all devices
>   
>   Make sure that "Hide iCloud books" are turned **OFF**
>
> More information:
>   https://miapple.me/ibooks-sync-pdf-files-ebooks-via-icloud/